# scala: how to rewrite this function using for comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have this piece of code with a couple of nasty nested checks...

I'm pretty sure it can be rewritten with a nice for comprehension, but I'm a bit confused about how to mix the pattern matching stuff

```
// first tries to find the token in a header: "authorization: ideas_token=xxxxx"
// then tries to find the token in the querystring: "ideas_token=xxxxx"
private def applicationTokenFromRequest(request: Request[AnyContent]): Option[String] = {

  val fromHeaders: Option[String] = request.headers.get("authorization")
  val tokenRegExp = """^\s*ideas_token\s*=\s*(\w+)\s*$""".r

  val tokenFromHeader: Option[String] = {
    if (fromHeaders.isDefined) {
      val header = fromHeaders.get
      if (tokenRegExp.pattern.matcher(header).matches) {
        val tokenRegExp(extracted) = header
        Some(extracted)
      } else {
        None
      }
    } else {
      None
    }
  }

  // try to find it in the queryString
  tokenFromHeader.orElse {
    request.queryString.get("ideas_token")
  }

}
```

any hint you can give me?

Comment: Probably better on the code review site

Comment: @NoelM: The question asks for concrete advice, not just code review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get rid of a lot of the cruft by just using the extractor in a `for`-comprehension:

```
val Token = """^\s*ideas_token\s*=\s*(\w+)\s*$""".r

val tokenFromHeader = for {
  Token(t) <- request.headers.get("authorization")
} yield t

tokenFromHeader orElse request.queryString.get("ideas_token")
```

But the following is even more concise, and a little clearer, to my eye:

```
val Token = """^\s*ideas_token\s*=\s*(\w+)\s*$""".r

request.headers.get("authorization") collect {
  case Token(t) => t
} orElse request.queryString.get("ideas_token")
```

The two are essentially equivalent, though—in both cases you're just pulling the value (if it exists) out of the `Option` and seeing if it matches the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks travis, one question, is it good style to Uppercase reg exps like Classes???

Comment: @opensas: It used to be necessary in cases like this (before 2.8, I believe), and yes, I personally think it's good style when you're using the `Regex` as an extractor (and I'm [not the only one](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/matching-regular-expressions.html?showComment=1263557644909#c3199199242085774480)).